# Exporting a runnable jar, opening it returns an UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

I currently wrote a simple GUI in Eclipse which runs as intended. I was hoping to export it so I can share it with my friend (who doesn't need to install eclipse and the java libraries). I tried all 3 library handling method Eclipse provides and none of them works. I read a little online and saw something about a manifest file, but wasn't quite sure what to do with it. Is it going to help? [image: This is what happens when I run it in the cmd]

This is where I placed the folder that comes with the .dll file. 
[image][image]
This is the result. Am I doing something wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the error messages in the first screenshot, what you are missing here is the native library - the software library written and compiled to native code specific to the operating system. What you will need to do is provide the libraries specific to the operating system on which your software will run, eg. dlls for 32 or 64 bit Windows. The manifest does not provide the capability to include those libraries.

When the program is run on Windows, Java will look for native libraries in the following locations:

- The current directory
- The directories in the PATH environment variable
- The directories in java.library.path (if it's specified)

It may be easiest to simply put all files in the one directory. If you do this, you should be able to run the program in the same way as you do now.

The `java.library.path` option is **only** needed if you want to put your native library files in a directory separate to the one in which you run your program and not on your PATH. It is only in this case that you will need to add `java.library.path`, eg. by adding `-Djava.library.path=c:\path\to\your\lib` after `java`. Also note that you may use a relative path, ie. a path that is relative to the directory you are in when you execute the command.

I also see from your later error messages that you have another dependency, but on a java library `LeapJava.jar`. As running a jar with `-jar` will only work if you have a single jar, but because you have more than one (your own program plus the dependency), you'll instead need to use the `-classpath` (or `-cp` for short) argument and add your main class. The classpath argument is a semicolon-separated list of classpath locations, while the main class is the one containing your `public static void main` method, eg. `your.package.name.YourMainClass`. So assuming your UI.jar is still in `C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Leap Data UI`, you should be able to navigate to that directory and execute with:

```
java -cp UI.jar;UI_lib\LeapJava.jar -Djava.library.path="UI_lib\x64" your.package.name.YourMainClass
```

Comment: So do I add this in my java code? I'm not quite sure about how to set the path explicitly. If do this explicitly does that mean my friend also need to do it too? Sorry, I'm fairly new to coding.

Comment: There are several things you need to do. First, you need to find the relevant .dll files that come with LeapJava. Then you'll need to give those files to whoever runs your program - they should be left as separate files, and do not need to be included with your jar. Finally, the library path needs to be included when you or your friend run the program. In your example you ran `java -jar UI.jar`, it's this that needs to be changed to include `-Djava.library.path=c:\path\to\lib\folder`.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the result of what I think I'm suppose to do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're no longer specifying your own program with the `-jar UI.jar` arguments, but I see that you also have LeapJava.jar as a dependency so that requires different arguments again - I'll amend my answer. Your java.library.path should be set to the folder containing the libraries, so `-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Leap Data UI\UI_lib\UI.jar"`. As an aside, I'd also like to suggest that for future questions you copy the text of the window and format it as code rather than screenshot it, as it helps in answering.

Comment: Would you also mind adding the package and class of containing your main method? ie, the `public static void main` method that is used to launch your program.

Comment: How do I add the package and the class containing my main. Do I just put the package with my source code next to it? Another thing, when I used this in my cmd: 'java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Leap Data UI\UI_lib\UI.jar' it only returns me with instructions on how to use the 'java' command.

Comment: My answer was previously updated to describe this - what you're typing in is significantly different

Comment: Oh, I see the updated answer now. Ignore my last comment. How do I get the package name and the main class? From the bin?

Comment: From your source code. The main class is the code that you wrote, containing the public static void main method. The package is the name of the package at the top of that file.

Comment: I placed the package containing my main class next to my runnable jar, and typed `java -cp UI.jar;UI_lib\LeapJava.jar -Djava.library.path="UI_lib\x64" Hello.Test` in the cmd. It returned `Could not find or load main class Hello.Test`.

Comment: We seem to be using different terms here - your runnable jar should already contain your main class. "package" is a concept in java for organising classes into hierarchies. So for example to create a class named Test, you'd write `public class Test`, and declare its package with `package Hello;` at the top of the file. What does your UI.jar contain?

Comment: My UI.jar only contains the class Test. If the .jar already contain my main class, then do I type `java -cp UI.jar;UI_lib\LeapJava.jar -Djava.library.path="UI_lib\x64" UI.jar` instead?

Comment: Btw, UI.jar is a runnable jar file of my class Test.

Comment: Does your Test class have a package specified? If not, use: `java -cp UI.jar;UI_lib\LeapJava.jar -Djava.library.path="UI_lib\x64" Test`

Comment: YES, I FIXED IT! IT WORKS NOW! Thanks you so much for helping.